# Amazon lex Slots break

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

hi i have 2 slots type in lex one is **Membership Number** and 2nd is **Pin**.
i wanted to know, in contact flow can we check Membership number from database before moving to second slot which is pin.
mean if we enter wrong membership number it check first if it is wrong then ask me again to say membership number (means check each slots 1 by 1 from db). hope so you understand my question.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a Lambda Function to check a database between every Slot if you want. So it would go like thus: AWS Connect -> Lex -> Lambda -> Database and then backwards.

Comment: You can also use Lambda directly from Connect but if you are using Lex anyway, might as well use Lambda to improve Lex's parsing and validation of Slots with your database at the same time.

Comment: @JayA.Little I added my lambda function in lex fulfillment block but it gives me an error I also post a question about that it gives me some error here is the link to that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62700757/invalid-lambda-response-received-error-response-from-lambda-unhandled